# Does PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable only apply to logged in user?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This might be more of a Linux question, but I am running a Pyspark job with a UDF that depends on a built-in module for Python3 (not Python2). So, basically the job bombs because the executor/driver is running Python2. Anyways, I want to set the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable to use Python3, but I am on a system that other people use to execute Pyspark jobs. I use a specific user account to execute my jobs, so I just want to make sure if I set that `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable that it will only apply to my account, and not others who it might effect if the executor python version suddenly changed because of me setting this.

Comment: The executors run in different machines, though. You're not guaranteed to get Python3 on them

Comment: If you edit `~/.bashrc`, it'll only be for that user account, yes. On windows, environment variables can also be set per user